# Adsense "unable to process your request at this time" about 10% of the time

Tags: google-adsense, problem

Lately I've been receiving screens like the following when I check the performance tab of my adsense account. In the screenshot, I use < email address > instead of the actual email address I use for my account.

[image]

When I see a screen like that, would it mean that google is taking a closer look at my website? would it mean I'm going to make more money? I'm trying to understand why in a one-week time span that I receive such messages 10% of the time, where as the time before that I never saw any of them. The only thing I did to the site in that time frame was try to optimize for speed.

Someone please enlighten me.

Comment: I am sure this has nothing to do with your site. These messages or similar messages can pop-up in the Google apps. I have gotten a few over the years. But you seem to be getting a lot of them lately. I am not sure why, but I am sure it has to do with connecting with the back-end or an internal error was tripped for which there is no other condition for. It could be missing data or a whole host of things. Not to worry. Unless they ring your door bell!!

Answer (score 1):

That is Google's "500 Internal Server" error.   Something went wrong building the page for you.   When I get this message in AdSense I usually refresh the page.

One thing that I've noticed causes this issue is logging out of Google (or switching Google accounts) in another tab.   I do so frequently enough that I now use Firefox for most of my browsing, but use Google Chrome for AdSense so that my Firefox tabs don't effect it.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a standard Google internal error message most likely because they are updating their services or because their services are overloaded.

Comment: what is difference between " this is look like " and "this looks like " ?